# asp.net core web api and 406 error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm trying to work through an example in the book ASP.NET Core Essentials and I'm getting a 406 not acceptable error (including a test with postman)

This is the model:

```html
namespace PatientRecordsApi.Models
{
    public class Patient
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string SocialSecurityNumber { get; set; }
    }
}​
```

This is the controller:

```html
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using PatientRecordsApi.Models;

namespace PatientRecordsApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class PatientController : Controller
    {
        Patient[] patients = new Patient[]
        {
            new Patient
            {
                Id = 1,
                FirstName = "John",
                LastName = "Smith",
                SocialSecurityNumber = "123550001"
            },
            new Patient
            {
                Id = 2,
                FirstName = "Jane",
                LastName = "Doe",
                SocialSecurityNumber = "123550002"
            },
            new Patient
            {
                Id = 3,
                FirstName = "Lisa",
                LastName = "Smith",
                SocialSecurityNumber = "123550003"
             }
            };

        // GET: api/patient
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Patient> Get()
        {
            return patients;
        }

       // GET api/patient/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public Patient Get(int id)
        {
            var patient = patients.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
            if (patient == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return patient;
        }
    }
}
​
```

This is the client:

```html
<body>
    <div>
        <h2>Patient Records</h2>
        <ul id="patients"></ul>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h2>Find Patient By ID</h2>
        <input type="text" id="patientId" size="5" />
        <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="find();" />
        <p id="patient" />
    </div>

    <script src="lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        var uri = 'api/Patient';
        debugger;
        $(document).ready(function () {

        var jqxhr = $.getJSON(uri)
            .done(function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (key, patient) {
                    $('<li>', {
                        text: formatPatientInfo(patient)
                    }).appendTo($('#patients'));
                });
            }).fail(function () { alert(jqxhr.error) })
              .always(function () { alert("always") });
        });
        function formatPatientInfo(patient) {
            if (patient && patient.lastName)
                return patient.lastName +
                ', ' + patient.firstName +
                ': ' + patient.socialSecurityNumber;
            else
                return 'No patient information found.';
        }
        function find() {
            var id = $('#patientId').val();
            $.getJSON(uri + '/' + id)
            .done(function (data) {
                $('#patient').text(formatPatientInfo(data));
            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                $('#patient').text('Error: ' + err);
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>​
```

Running a debugger on the client shows that "data is undefined". I'm guessing that the data in the patients model that is being returned is not in a correct json format but I don't know how to fix that?  Or is it something else? Thanks.

Comment: [Route("api/[controller]")] ,how u r routing .I guess there is some mistake with routing

Comment: Did you make sure the web api is executed? you can click F12 and go to the network tab, and inspect the request to see what is being returned

Comment: Thanks Hina and Haitham for looking at this - got me thinking.  It turns out that the real problem is that the book I'm trying to follow used some bad code examples.  I started over with the standard Core template for Web Api and just put in the model and controller code for Patient without any of the author's other changes - now it works fine.